# jQuery Validate pick and choose error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How would I pick and choose what error messages to show when using jquery validate?

Here is my init:

```
    $('#msform').validate({
        //errorPlacement: function() {},
        messages: {
            email: {
                email: "Please enter a valid email.",
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
            $(element).css('border-color', '#a94442');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).css('border-color', '');
        }
    });
```

I don't want the `required` label error to show. I only want the invalid email label to show. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Nic, try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" always required. Nothing and blanks are invalid.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="msform">
<label for="field">Required: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="email" name="email">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$("#msform").validate({
        rules: {
            email: "required email",
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "",
                email: "Invalid Email",

            }


        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

Comment: Nic, I have updated my answer. I believe you need to set email field as not mandatory.

Comment: This is not what I mean. I want the email field to be mandatory but I don't want the required error label to show up. I only want a label to show up when the email is not typed correctly. I have other functionality for the required field (other than the label) so it still needs to be mandatory.